# Should I include my preprints in Google Scholar after their publication in a journal, if they have been cited?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, preprint

I published my manuscript on a preprint server (bioRxiv) a few months ago. We then submitted the paper to a journal for peer-review and we are currently at the final stages of it. In the meantime, my preprint has been cited by a couple of papers that were recently published.

Is it OK to include both the preprint and the accepted paper on my Google Scholar page to account for all citations of my work?

Comment: Not an answer. When your paper is accepted/published you should consider contacting the people who cite the preprint so they can update the citation.

Comment: You can use the "merge" option in Google Scholar for the published version and the preprint.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You should write that up as an answer ... perhaps adding a bit more detail about how to achieve/find the merging.

Answer (score 2):

From the Google Scholar instructions:

Select both versions of the article and click the "Merge" button. You will then see both citations for the article listed. Select the best citation to the article (you can edit it later if you wish) and click "Merge". This will merge the two versions (preserving all the citations).